# Drawing polygons that share boundaries using Google My Maps

Tags: administrative-boundaries, google-mymaps

I am relatively new to GIS and I am facing a problem to maintain a layer of polygons that share boundaries. I use google my maps to edit the polygons but they are full of gaps and overlaps. 
How can I create polygons that share boundaries and have no gaps and overlaps?
[image: overlaps]

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no answer to this question. The only way is to do this in another software, such as QGIS or ArcGIS.